# getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a function to read data from db.but this always returns error..i dont have much knowledge in android..looking for some help

```
10-03 11:33:05.870: E/AndroidRuntime(1321): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projects.myworldsafe/com.projects.myworldsafe.DeailedView}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

.

```
String getItemDetailsWp(String id){
System.out.print(id);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String[] params=new String[]{id};
String selectQuery = "SELECT Content  FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS +" WHERE "+ITEM_ID+"=?";
Cursor c=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,params);   
 c.moveToFirst();
 int index= c.getCount();
 int indexd= c.getColumnIndex(ITEM_CONTENT); 
 System.out.print("Count query"+indexd);
 return c.getString(index);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
return c.getString(indexd);
```

it is what you actually want to get value of. you used `index` there,which returns number of record in your cursor.

also better practice is:

```
String getItemDetailsWp(String id){
System.out.print(id);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String[] params=new String[]{id};
String selectQuery = "SELECT Content  FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS +" WHERE "+ITEM_ID+"=?";
Cursor c=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,params);   
if(c.getCount()>0){
    c.moveToFirst();
    int index= c.getCount();
    int indexd= c.getColumnIndex(ITEM_CONTENT); 
    System.out.print("Count query"+index);// use index instead of indexd to print total records in query
    return c.getString(index);// return value of column number specified in indexd
}
else
    return "";// when no records found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the right code

```
int index= c.getCount(); // this will return total rows found
int indexd= c.getColumnIndex(ITEM_CONTENT);  // this is the column index by giving the column name.
System.out.print("Count query"+indexd);
return c.getString(indexd); // here you need to pass the column index but you passing the index which was total number of rows
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,params);
```

is returning cursor with size 0, change your code to check if the cursor has items or not, then move to first position by:

```
Cursor c=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,params);   
if(c.getCount()>0)
{
 c.moveToFirst();
int index= c.getCount();
 int indexd= c.getColumnIndex(ITEM_CONTENT); 
 System.out.print("Count query"+indexd);
 return c.getString(index);
}
return "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to read from an empty resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database , The query is returning a cursor of size 0 , So you are trying to access cursor at index 0, hence the error.
Rethink over the query and check the database for values.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably accessing a 0 row cursor. Change to :

```
// moveToFirst itself will return false if there is no entry on Cursor
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    int cursorCount = c.getCount();
    int indexd = c.getColumnIndex(ITEM_CONTENT); 
    System.out.print("Count query"+index);
    // You should getString(ColumnIndex) not CursorCount
    return c.getString(indexd);
} else
    return "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting index out of bounds exception as you are passing number of records in place of column-number.
As best coding practices, check cursor for records, i.e. it is empty or contains records.
Use this

```
String getItemDetailsWp(String id){
System.out.print(id);
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String[] params=new String[]{id};
String selectQuery = "SELECT Content  FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS +" WHERE "+ITEM_ID+"=?";
Cursor c=db.rawQuery(selectQuery,params);   
if(c.getCount()>0){
c.moveToFirst();
int index= c.getCount();
int indexd= c.getColumnIndex(ITEM_CONTENT); 
System.out.print("Count query"+index);
return c.getString(indexd);
}
else
return "";// when no records found
}
```